# tf.keras.models.Sequential model cannot fit with input type tf.Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written a simple tf.keras.models.Sequential model. When I try to fit it with data and labels as tf.Tensor, it gives me some error. However I can fit it with numpy array with exactly the same underlying data. Why is it?

I am using tensorflow 1.13 with only CPU. I checked the [fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#fit) function of tf.keras.models.Sequential but it says both tf.Tensor and numpy array can be used as data and label as long as their types match.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

# very simple keras Sequential model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# use tf.Tensor as data and label
data = tf.constant([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
label = tf.constant([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]])
# This throws the following error
# InvalidArgumentError: Index out of range using input dim 2; input has only 2 dims [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
model.fit(data, label, epochs=10)

# use numpy array with the same underlying data and label
data = data.numpy()
label = label.numpy()
# This works
model.fit(data, label, epochs=10)
```

The first fit does not work and throws the following error. But the second works. This is interesting because they have exacly the same underlying data

Comment: There are two problems in my code:

1. **tf.enable_eager_execution** is turned on. That gives the benefit of allowing calling numpy() on tf.Tensor but gives unclear error message when the model is fitting. Instead of telling me to add steps_per_epoch as a parameter to fit call, It prints the error message I showed as comment in the code. One lesson I learned is to be careful with eager execution.

2. **steps_per_epoch** should be added as a parameter when the model is fitted on tf.Tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like perhaps you are using tensorflow 2.0 because of the call to `.numpy()` which I believe doesn't exist on 1.13 (perhaps you realise already but you can check the version with `tf.__version__`)

If you intend to use 1.13 then you need to make 2 changes to allow the call to `fit` to execute without error.

1. You must convert your input tensors to have type float32
2. You must pass a `steps_per_epoch` argument

This code, for example, does not throw any errors:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


data = tf.constant([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]], dtype=tf.float32)
label = tf.constant([[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]], dtype=tf.float32)
model.fit(data, label, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=2)
```

Comment: 1. Interestingly, my tensorflow is 1.13.1, not sure if that's the reason why Tensor.numpy() is there.
2. The solution does work. But may I understand why the codes I have before does not work? Looks like the tensorflow doc does not ban the use of tf.Tensor as input without specifying steps_per_epoch.

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer the 'why' question I am afraid. I ran it without `steps_per_epoch` and hit an error message telling me to add it. I added it and it works. Hence the answer above :-)

Comment: Later I found I forgot to put the tf.enable_eager_execution()(This is actually in the code I ran locally) after I import tensorflow and that turns out to the tricky part. Without this sentence, numpy() cannot be called on tf.Tensor and I can get the same reminder asking me to put steps_per_epoch as in your case. With enable_eager_execution turned on, I will get the error message I displayed as comments in the code and it gives some unexpected output and error message and  making debugging harder in this case.